# Can't get user login info in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm creating a REST API using `Node js` and `expressJs`, but suddenly I have faced a problem when I tried to create a user then I can create it like this way:

```
/**
 * save user data from the user model
 */

router.post("/users", async (req, res) => {
  const user = new User(req.body);

  try {
    await user.save();
    res.status(201).send( user);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});
```

after creating a user I can see a response in postman.

But When I tried to go `/users/login` routes then I have faced a problem it shows me `400 bad requests` also can't get any response. here is my code:

```
/**
 * User login.
 */

router.post("/users/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findByCredentials(
      req.body.email,
      req.body.password
    );
    res.send( user);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send();
  }
});
```

```
/**
 * user login crendentials
 */

userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async (email, password) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (!user) {
    throw new Error("Unable to login");
  }

  const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

  if (!isMatch) {
    throw new Error("Unable to login");
  }
  
};
```

Any suggestion will highly appreciated
Thanks.

Comment: "it shows me 400 bad requests" - well, in the catch statement you have `res.status(400).send();` At a minimum, include the exception details if you expect any help other than pointing out that you wrote the 400 response into the response when the request fails.

Comment: Hi @MetroSmurf, is there any problem in try block with `findByCredentials` ?

Comment: Maybe `res.send(user);` should be `req.send(user);`???

Comment: Nope, it returns a response, not a request.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by returning the `user`, like this way:

```
/**
 * user login crendentials
 */

userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async (email, password) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (!user) {
    throw new Error("Unable to login");
  }

  const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

  if (!isMatch) {
    throw new Error("Unable to login");
  }
 return user; //-------->>>>>>> add this line
  
};
```